# Best NSLayoutConstraint for Animated Removal/Addition of side by side items

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, autolayout

I have two `UIViews`, best shown as ASCII art:

```
|-padding-[view1]-[view2]-padding-|
```

I want to animate the removal of `view2` by fading it out (in place) and simultaneously stretching `view1` to fill it's spot

```
|-padding-[    view1    ]-padding-|
```

In addition to that, `view2` can come back in and should reverse that animation... AND the same can happen for `view1` such that

```
|-padding-[    view2    ]-padding-|
```

I know how to do this without AutoLayout, but it seems like we are all noobs when it comes to this new API. What is the best way to approach advanced animations like this using Autolayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try putting view1 and view2 inside of a another view (called container below). The container view would be constrained like this:

```
|-padding-[container]-padding-|
```

Then I would constrain view1 and view2's left and right edges to the container view. The expansion and shrinking of the buttons would be taken care of by animating the constants of these constraints.

```
|-[view1]-halfContainerWidth-|
|-halfContainerWidth-[view2]-|
```

For example, when you want to hide view2:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    view2.alpha = 0.0;
    view1RightConstraint.constant = 0.0;
};
```

To show view2 again:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    view2.alpha = 1.0;
    CGFloat containerWidth = container.frame.size.width;
    view1RightConstraint.constant = containerWidth / 2.0;
};
```

You could do this without the container view, but I think having it makes things more simple. Essentially you are just managing the constant values for the right edge constraint of the view on the left and the left edge constraint of the view on the right. When only 1 view is visible the constant is 0 and when both are visible it is the width of the container/2.